# React-Native-Maps: How to animate to coordinate?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, react-redux, react-native-maps

I am using the following code with no success:

//Inside of NativeBase Container

```
        <MapView.Animated
           ref="map"
           style = {styles.map}
           showsUserLocation = {true}
           zoomEnabled = {true}
           showsMyLocationButton = {true}
           showsCompass = {true}
           showScale = {true}
           showsIndoors = {true}
           mapType = {this.state.mapTypes[this.state.mapTypeCode]}
        />
```

//Inside of componentDidMount of the class

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position.coords);
    this.setState({position: initialPosition});

    let tempCoords = {
      latitude: Number(position.coords.latitude),
      longitude: Number(position.coords.longitude)
    }

    this.refs.map.animateToCoordinate(tempCoords, 1);

  }, function (error) { alert(error) },

);
```

But an error occurs saying there is no such function animateToCoordinate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had some issues where this.refs is undefined, unless I bind a reference to this in the constructor to the function I am using this.refs in. In your case, try this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._getCoords = this._getCoords.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        position: null
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this._getCoords();
}

_getCoords = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
            var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position.coords);
            this.setState({position: initialPosition});
            let tempCoords = {
                latitude: Number(position.coords.latitude),
                longitude: Number(position.coords.longitude)
            }
            this._map.animateToCoordinate(tempCoords, 1);
          }, function (error) { alert(error) },
     );
};

render() {
    return (
         <MapView.Animated
             ref={component => this._map = component}
          />
    );

}
```

Although using string refs is still possible, I believe that is legacy now, so I've also updated the MapView ref to the newer way. See: [Ref Example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#setnativeprops-to-clear-textinput-value)

Comment: how to show Marker on the bottom of Map not in (center center) position ?

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately now animateToCoordinate is deprecated and if you want to do the same, you should use [animateCamera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods) or [animateToRegion](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods) instead.

```
render() {
  return ( 
    <MapView style = {styles.maps}
      ref = {(mapView) => { _mapView = mapView; }}
      initialRegion = {{
        latitude: 6.8523,
        longitude: 79.8895,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      }}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity 
       onPress = {() => _mapView.animateToRegion({
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE
      }, 1000)}>
      <Text>Tap</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
```

}

Comment: `animateToRegion` needs `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta`. on the other hand, `animateCamera` does not, so a bit easier if not tracking zoom values. ie., `_mapView.animateCamera({ center: { latitude, longitude }})`

Answer (score 8):

In my case I used **[animateToCoordinate()](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods)** like follows and it works for me:

```
  var _mapView: MapView;

  render() {
      return ( 
        <MapView style = {styles.maps}
          ref = {(mapView) => { _mapView = mapView; }}
          initialRegion = {{
            latitude: 6.8523,
            longitude: 79.8895,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity 
           onPress = {() => _mapView.animateToCoordinate({
            latitude: LATITUDE,
            longitude: LONGITUDE
          }, 1000)}>
          <Text>Tap</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution as the ones provided above didn't work for me:

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const defaultRegion = {
latitude: 59.9139, 
longitude: 10.7522,
latitudeDelta: 0.0922/1,
longitudeDelta: 0.0521/1
}

const newLocation = {
latitude: 2.0469,
longitude: 45.3182
}
```

```
const MapScreen = () => {

const mapViewRef = useRef(null);

return (
    <View style={styles.mapContainer}>

        <MapView ref={ mapViewRef } style={styles.map} initialRegion = { defaultRegion } >

          ...

        </MapView>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress = {() => mapViewRef.current.animateToRegion( newLocation, 1000)} >
            <Text>Move Location</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  );
};
```

Main takeaways:

```
1. const mapViewRef = useRef(null);
2. ref={ mapViewRef }
3. onPress = {() => mapViewRef.current.animateToRegion( newLocation, 1000)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

```
const animateToCoordinat = (lat, long) => {
  mapView?.animateCamera({
    center: {
      latitude: lat,
      longitude: long,
    },
    duration: {
      1000,
    }
  });
}
```

[https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#:~:text=current%20camera%20configuration.-,animateCamera,-camera%3A%20Camera%2C%20%7B%20duration](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#:%7E:text=current%20camera%20configuration.-,animateCamera,-camera%3A%20Camera%2C%20%7B%20duration)

You can use `setCamera` method also.

Answer (score 0):

I my case worked with Animate Camera function, i used <MapView.Animated/>, this component generates a cool animation ...

```
<MapView.Animated
    provider = { Platform.OS === 'android' ? PROVIDER_GOOGLE : PROVIDER_DEFAULT } // remove if not using Google Maps
    style = { styles_l.map }       
    ref = {(map) => (this.map = map)}
    initialRegion = { this.state.region }
    followsUserLocation = { true}
    showsCompass = { true}
    showsUserLocation = { true}
    onRegionChange = {() => this.handleChangeRegion }
    onRegionChangeComplete = {() => this.handleChangeRegion.bind(this) }>
</MapView.Animated >
```

This component will call this function:

```
handleChangeRegion = (region) => {
    this.map.animateCamera({ center: region });
}
```

I hope this can help you too, It's really a nice component! and a very usefull, congratulations to those involved.